# How to get value attribute in views

Tags: html, django

Hello is there a way to get 'value' attribute from HTML template into views.py and use it there??
HTML:

```
<form class="card__delete" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
                        <button value="{{item.id}}" class="card__delete__button"  name="delete" type="submit">&#10008</button>
                    </form>
```

views.py

```
class TodoView(UserPassesTestMixin, CreateView):
   model = Item
   template_name = 'home/todo.html'
   form_class = ItemCreationForm
   def test_func(self):
       return self.request.user.username in self.request.path
   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
      context['card'] = Card.objects.get(user=self.request.user, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
      return context
   def post(self, request, pk, username):
      if 'delete' in self.request.POST:
         Item.objects.get(id=pk).delete()
         print('deleted')
         return redirect('home-page')
```

Answer (score 0):

The value is in request.POST, so you should be able to access it with

```
value = self.request.POST.get('delete', None)
```

Take care to validate that value before using the id of an object to do anything catastrophic to it (such as `.delete()`). It's not being validated through a form, and a random hacker on the internet might try posting back random numbers which might be the id of other objects

Added after reading comment:

Data pulled out of request.POST is raw data. I don't think CSRF token can protect against a person who uses inspect object in his browser and changes the value of that button before clicking it. I may be wrong.

Anyway, if you can check the value using a queryset of the object type with a filter for objects that this user is permitted to delete, then do. For example,

```
value = request.POST.get("delete", None)
if value:
    obj = Card.objects.filter(
       user=self.request.user ).get( pk=value) 
    # will raise CardDoesNotExist if value isn't one of user's objects, 
    # because it's been filtered out
     obj.delete()
```

Comment: But i would like to delete this item. What should I do? I thought {% csrf__token %} takes care of it.

Comment: @Kay have edited answer. Firefox trouble, StackOverflow back to normal using Chrome!